# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.cython_bbox'

Tags: python, windows, cython

I'm a student and a complete newbie, so please forgive me if this is a basic question. I have followed the instructions to run PCL model (https://github.com/ppengtang/pcl.pytorch) on the voc2007 data by following the instructions on the github page.

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.10.5, and as far as I can tell I've installed all dependencies including Visual Studio Code C++ libraries, SDK etc., although I had a lot of trouble trying to install cython_bbox.

When I run in CMD:

```
python tools/test_net.py --cfg configs/baselines/vgg16_voc2007.yaml \ --load_ckpt Outputs/vgg16_voc2007/$MODEL_PATH \ --dataset voc2007trainval
```

I get the following:

```
C:\Users####\py_virtual_env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\detection\anchor_utils.py:63: UserWarning: Failed to initialize NumPy: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xf (Triggered internally at ..\torch\csrc\utils\tensor_numpy.cpp:68.)
device: torch.device = torch.device("cpu"),
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users####\pcl.pytorch\tools\test_net.py", line 14, in
from core.test_engine import run_inference
File "C:\Users####\pcl.pytorch\lib\core\test_engine.py", line 36, in
from core.test import im_detect_all
File "C:\Users####\pcl.pytorch\lib\core\test.py", line 43, in
import utils.boxes as box_utils
File "C:\Users####\pcl.pytorch\lib\utils\boxes.py", line 54, in
import utils.cython_bbox as cython_bbox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils.cython_bbox'
```

In the lib\utils folder, there are two files: cython_bbox.c and cython_bbox.pyx. This appears to be the root of the issue but I have no idea what exactly the issue is or how to fix it.

For information, I also have:

```
Requirement already satisfied: cython_bbox in c:\users####\py_virtual_env\lib\site-packages (0.1.3)
```

I've searched online for a solution but cannot find one.
I'd appreciate any help.